# css based a link hover activate/deactivate div

Tags: html, css, hover, drop-down-menu, position

any idea what am I missing at the link: ** http://jsfiddle.net/AnUZ7/2/ **

I'm trying to make a dropdown like at Zerply

[image]

```
<a href="#" class="setting">Setting</a>

<ul>
    <li><a href="#">Lorem</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Ipsum</a></li>
</ul>
```

css here:

```
ul {
    position: absolute;
    background: orange;
    width: 10em;
    left: -999em; 
}

a.setting:hover ul {
    left: auto;
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try replacing `a.setting:hover ul {...}` to

```
a.setting:hover + ul,
ul.submenu:hover {...}
```

Edited fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/AnUZ7/4/

The `.first + .second` selector selects the next element after `.first`.
The `.first ~ .after-first` selector select all elements after `.first`.
These selectors are not working on Internet Explorer 6, but hopefully that is not a big problem in 2011.

Beware the (possible) margin/padding/other gaps between the `a` and its `ul` in your actual design! If the mouse pointer falls between them, the menu will disappear.

Comment: ah yes, dropdown appears now, Thanks!. but the problem is; the dropdown block disappears when I roll over it :/ hmmm....

Comment: ps, what is "+" in there? never used that before :/

Comment: amazing! thanks a lot!!!! i spent hours on this with googling for answer and trying. but you helped in minutes :)